# Error when trying to convert base64 into pdf (can't open file) using Python

Tags: python, pdf, base64

I'm trying to convert a base64 string into a pdf file.

Sample Code:

```
import base64
b64 = 'TXkgYmluYXJ5IHN0cmluZw==\n'
bytes = base64.b64decode(b64)
f = open('file.pdf', 'wb')
f.write(bytes)
f.close()
```

The file is successfully saved as a pdf but whenever I try to open it shows the following error:
[image]

Are there any additional steps I need to make in order to make the file readable? Thanks

Comment: if the base64 data is actually pdf data, your code should work. But I can' verify that based on the given example.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Thanks the code you suggested gives the following error:   a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: @jps agreed, didn't go through the statement

Comment: @jps Hi thanks for replying. Could it be because the pdf is scanned instead of saved from a doc file? It seems that my code works fine with pdfs saved form a ms word file ( as in I convert the pdf to base64 and then use my code to decode & save it again). Not sure if it works for scanned pdfs...

Comment: Another explanation is the base64 strings I have are stored in the MS SQL server and the length of viewable/copy-able strings is limited to 32795. So when I pass the base64 strings to the base64.b64decode function, it's not the complete string and thus the file can't be properly saved

Comment: the length might indeed play a role here. Scanned pdf files usually have images as content and are therefore larger than pure text based pdf files. But then it's more a problem with your way of storing the data and not a problem of decoding.

Comment: I did the same you did with a byte array downloaded from an API and it worked.
Before decoding the downloaded bytes got from "response.content" I was facing the same problem you are.

Answer (score 0):

Please also try `urlsafe_b64decode` for decoding. I had the same issue in Ruby and the url safe decoding did the trick.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).